# Enabling LinkedIn "Client Credential Flow" functionality

Tags: linkedin-api

Trying to get LinkedIn's "Client Credential Flow" functionality enabled for one of our applications so that end users can use their LinkedIn credentials to log into the application. LinkedIn's own documentation states that this feature is disabled by default and to contact them for assistance - https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v2/oauth2-client-credentials-flow.

Opened a support case with them and was directed several times to post this request to Stack Overflow where their developer support team would assist.

Has anyone had any success getting in touch with LinkedIn developer support on Stack Overflow? And if they have have they been able to get client credential flow enabled for their application?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming and LinkedIn have no right to be sending people here to ask it. They never seem to respond here anyway.

Answer (score 0):

A dev wouldn’t use the two legged flow for user/member auth. You’d be using the three legged flow for that and that should be available for public/open/self-serve apis. The client credential flow would be for an application level grant. May want to reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/client-credentials-flow